# Trying to add each table item to an array using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Basically what the title says... just having trouble getting it to work and couldn't find a solution online.

Code:

```
    var arr=new Array();
    $('#tableC tr').each(function() {
        var tr = $(this);
        tr.find('td').each(arr, function() {
            $(this).val();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Indeed. @Slaks♦ is correct. Use .text() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var arr = [];
    $('#tableC td').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).text());
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're *completely* miscalling [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each).

Instead, write

```
tr.find('td').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

You could also write

```
var arr = $("#tableC tr td").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

Comment: `arr.append` ? What are you using Chrome v18 with support for ECMAScript 7th edition? ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

http://jsfiddle.net/pPxcE/

#### Edit

code

```
var arr=new Array();
$('#tableC tr').each(function() {
    var tr = $(this);
    tr.find('td').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but it may be because you posted a link to another site in lieu of the actual code for your solution.

Comment: Please put more than just a link in your answer.  In particular, you should include the code here.

Comment: everyone does... that's what fiddles are for.  I've never gotten a downvote for using jsfiddle... posters are even *told* to use the site to help us answer their questions.

Comment: @Joseph: StackOverflow is intended to be an independent repository of questions and answers. Sometimes jsFiddle is down (or extremely slow), making your answer useless at those times to future readers. I'll +1 for your solution, and for the update. :o)

Comment: @patrickdw Thank you, patrick. I'll use it as strictly supplementary from now on.